# Using two competing form gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I want to use both the [simple_form gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) and the [nested_form gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) for a single form. However, one starts `simple_form_for` and the other starts `nested_form_for`. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) instead of nested_form.